# Is there a way to have an umbrella term for multiple values in my entire excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a massive excel sheet and a lot of times there are different names for the same thing I'm referring to.  Is there a way to build an association map or umbrella term that I can refer to in formulas that will search all items under that umbrella term.

For example, my umbrella term could be "Food Products"

Under food products could be a variety of things like "Sandwiches," "Soda," and "Pizza."

So if you do a sumif for example, and I use "Food Products" as my criteria range, it will look at "Sandwiches," "Soda," and "Pizza."

Comment: You can either create a new column and populate it with "Food Products" where appropriate or maybe try a "Named Range".  Look for that under the Formula tab.  A named range can't contain a space so it will have to be named FoodProducts.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about the Named Range option.  My goal is to use a named range as the criteria portion of a sumifs function.  It's not working as hoped.  I would like it to go through all the values of the Named Range options but it's currently not doing that